# How to create filtered reports in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Creating reports in `WPF`.

I have two related tables.

Table A-Customer:

```
CustomerID(PK)
Names
Phone Number
Customer Num
```

Table B-Items:

```
Products
Price
CustomerID
```

I want to be able to generate a report like this:

```
CustomerA
Items     Price
Item A    10
Item B    10
Item C    10
---------------
Total     30
```

So this is what I have done:

```
<Window x:Class="ReportViewerWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
    assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" 
    Title="Customer Report" Height="300" Width="400">

 <Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1">
        <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer1"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
 </Grid>
```

Then I created a dataset and loaded the two tables, followed by a report wizard (dragged all the available fields and dropped them to the Values pane).

The code behind the WPF window is this:

```
public partial class CustomerReport : Window  
{
    public CustomerReport()  
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
        _reportViewer.Load += ReportViewer_Load;  

    } 

    private bool _isReportViewerLoaded;  

    private void ReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isReportViewerLoaded)
        {
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
            HM2DataSet dataset = new HM2DataSet();
            dataset.BeginInit();
            reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet";//This is the dataset name
            reportDataSource1.Value = dataset.CustomerTable;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../../Report3.rdlc";
            dataset.EndInit();
            HM2DataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter funcTableAdapter = new HM2DataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter();
            funcTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
            funcTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.CustomerTable);
            _reportViewer.RefreshReport();
            _isReportViewerLoaded = true;
         }
     }
```

As you might have guessed this loaded this list of customer with items and price:

```
Customer    Items     Price
Customer A  Items A    10
Customer A  Items B    10
Customer B  Items D    10
Customer B  Items C    10
```

How can I fine-tune this report to look like the one above, where the user can filter the customer he wants displayed on the report? Thanks in advance for the help. I would have preferred to use `LINQ` whenever filtering data